# How do you create dynamic forms using XML and angular?

Tags: angular, xml

I like to use an to generate XML file that dropdown, buttons and I'm not sure what to do. I'm very new to angular so this is a challenge but I've imported the XML file to the system and now I'm having difficulty going through the XML and generating the controls and displaying the info.

Example of XML

```
{
    "pageControls": [
        {
            "controlType": "dropdown",
            "controlCaption": "Get email?",
            "selectedValue": "default",
            "options": [
                {
                    "display": "default",
                    "value": "def"
                }, {
                    "display": "other",
                    "value": "oth"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "controlType": "button",
            "controlAction": "save",
            "buttonText": "save",
            "buttonIcon": ""
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: You want to generate forms using XML or JSON ?

Comment: I would like to generate forms using XML

Answer (score 0):

You can use reactive forms to build dynamic Forms. You can create the data from whatever source data you have. XML or JSON.

[Kindly check the below link for reference](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/angular-basics-creating-dynamic-forms-using-formarray-angular)